# c++ connect() keeps returning WSATIMEDOUT over internet but not localy

Tags: c++, winapi, sockets, winsock, ip

For some reason, my chat application always gets WSATIMEDOUT  when trying to connect to another person over the internet.

```
int len_ip = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_EDIT_IP));
char ipBuffer[16];
SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hWnd,ID_EDIT_IP),WM_GETTEXT,16,(LPARAM)ipBuffer);
long host_ip = inet_addr(ipBuffer);




int initializeConnection(long host_ip, HWND hWnd) {
    // initialize winsock
    WSADATA wdata;
    int result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wdata);
    if (result != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // setup socket
    tcp_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (tcp_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        return 0;
    }

    // setup socket address
    SOCKADDR_IN tcp_sock_addr;
    tcp_sock_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    tcp_sock_addr.sin_port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;
    tcp_sock_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = host_ip;

     // connect to server
     if (connect(tcp_sock,(SOCKADDR*)&tcp_sock_addr,sizeof(tcp_sock_addr)) ==     SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return 0;
    }
    HRESULT hr = WSAGetLastError();

    // set socket in asynchronous mode
    if (WSAAsyncSelect(tcp_sock,hWnd,SOCKET_TCP,  FD_READ | FD_WRITE | FD_CONNECT | FD_CLOSE) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
 }
```

For some reason it works perfectly fine on local network between computers, but totally screws up over the internet. WSATIMEDOUT is always returned (not connection refused, so its not a port problem). It makes me believe something is wrong with the IP but why on earth can it work on local addresses (like 192.168.2.4)

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure the person you're trying to connect to is not behind a firewall, NAT gateway or otherwise unreachable ? An easy way to check if it's an error in your program or the network is to simply telnet to that host and port combination. If that fails too, it's network related.

Comment: Yes, even if they would be I would get a "connection refused" or similiar afaik. The server has opened the router ports and let the program through windows firewall.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Many firewalls/routes will simply drop the packets and you get a timeout, not a "connection refused". Please test with telnet.

Comment: @nos: Using telnet to test for open TCP ports is a great solution.  @KaiserJohaan: Only if the firewall is configured to send a "port unreachable" ICMP message.  For a while, ["stealth" firewalls were all the rage](http://www.grc.com/su/portstatusinfo.htm).

Comment: Another thing is the `tcp_sock_addr.sin_port = SERVER_TCP_PORT;` , how is SERVER_TCP_PORT defined ? This should normally be `tcp_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_TCP_PORT);` unless SERVER_TCP_PORT is already in network byte order.

Comment: SERVER_TCP_PORT is defined through:      #define SERVER_TCP_PORT 12385 also how does one do a telnet test? tried googling but not sure i got right hit

Comment: Ok, then with your code you are not connecting to port 12385, you are connecting to port 24880 . Change your code to ` tcp_sock_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_TCP_PORT); ` (or make sure port 24880 is the one you've opened in the remote firewall.)

Comment: @KaiserJohaan  You'd have to change the server code too, to actually listen on port 12385 too btw. For a telnet test you simply open a command/DOS window and run the command `telnet 192.168.1.1 12345` , first argumet is the IP address, second is the port. Telnet might not be installed by default, if so go to(for win-7 atleast) `Control Panel->Uninstall a Program->Turn Windows features on or off` and check the  `Telnet Client`

Comment: nos, that sounds like a very good reason, im going to try it asap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewalls and/or Nat-routers perhaps? You will need hole punching: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching

Answer (score 0):

It could be a firewall configured to drop incoming requests instead of rejecting them.  Sometimes this is called "stealth" mode.